# Gulp sass not compiling for loop with #{$i} tag

Tags: npm, sass, gulp

Having a problem with Gulp sass, it's not compiling my file.

```
Unknown word You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
```

Code css:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-#{$i} {
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: (100% / 12) * $i;
        -webkit-flex-basis: (100% / 12) * $i;
        flex-basis: (100% / 12) * $i;
        max-width: (100% / 12) * $i;
    }
}
```

Code gulp:

```
gulp.task( 'sass', function() {
    return gulp.src( SOURCEPATHS.sassSource )
        .pipe( autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions']} ) )
        .pipe( sass({ includePaths: ['node_modules'] }, { outputStyle: 'compressed' }).on('error', sass.logError) )
        .pipe( mmq({ log: false }) )
        .pipe( cssmin() )
        .pipe( rename({suffix: '.min'}) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest(APPPATH.css) );
});
```

Error with this tag **#{$i}** - without this - gulp compile css file.

There could be a problem? I have read a lot about gulp-postcss - And try with it, but the result is the same - ERROR

Comment: Error is pretty clear. Run autoprefixer and other postcss plugins after sass.

Comment: Thanks - problem solve. You can submit your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.pipe( autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions']} ) )
```

Need to set after **sass**

Answer (score 0):

As per @TheDancingCode's comment, the fix for me was to run AutoPrefixer after SASS.

"Run autoprefixer and other postcss plugins after sass"

```
gulp.task("sass", function () {
    return gulp.src([`${paths.scss}**/*.scss`, `!${paths.scss}vendor/**/*`])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.contentRoot));
```

This seems obvious to me now, since SASS may be applying variables to property values.  If so, they can contain values which may need to be vendor-prefixed. Hence the requirement.